# How do I store a command in a variable and only execute it when used?

Tags: powershell, variables, command

```
##$parseDateTaken is not defined yet but will be before $DateDir is set.
##It's being used as a toggle to include or exclude the year directory.

$YearDir = "\" + {(Get-Date $parseDateTaken).Year}
...
$DateDir = $YearDir + "\" + $parseDateTaken
```

How can get the block of code to run when $YearDir is used?  Right now it only interprets the whole thing as a string.  I want to keep it a oneliner.

Comment: I would use [`$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56627626/1701026) for this.

Comment: `$YearDir = { "\" + ((Get-Date $parseDateTaken).Year) }; $DateDir = (& $YearDir) + "\" + $parseDateTaken`