# Updating variables within variables in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I don't know much about Powershell but I try to learn.
Can you help me to understand and solve what I want to do:

```
$string1=""

$complicatedString1 = "This is a complicated $string1"
$complicatedString2 = "$complicatedString1 too"

$string1 = "Test"

$complicatedString1 -> Should state now: This is a complicated Test
$complicatedString2 -> Should state now: This is a complicated Test too.

$string1 = "question"

$complicatedString1 -> Should state now: This is a complicated question
$complicatedString2 -> Should state now: This is a complicated question too.

and so on.
```

The idea sounds simple: I want to define strings that serve as templates, but with variable content.
In this case I want to manipulate $string1 and update $complicatedstring 1 and 2 so that any change of $string1 gets reflected in those strings.

$string1 would change frequently and at the moment I have no approach how get the changed values into those strings. Basically the're just placeholders to wait for being changed.

Comment: Your description is still a little vague. The content of a variable is defined in the moment you assign it. If `$String1` is still empty and you define another variable including `$String1` it will stay empty. You would need to re-assign the new variable AFTER you assigned something to `$String1` to reflect this change in the new variable. You might show or explain a little bit more of your use case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to expand variable in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915420/how-to-expand-variable-in-powershell)

Comment: Put your  `complicatedString1`and `complicatedString2` in single quotes and than use: `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($complicatedString1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, but I think your question is about using template strings you can alter using new strings-to-insert.

The most elegant way to do that I think is by making use of the PowerShell `-f` format operator like this:

```
# the template strings
$complicatedString1 = "This is a complicated {0}"
$complicatedString2 = "{0} too"

# use the template strings to return new strings
$string1 = $complicatedString1 -f "Test"                # --> "This is a complicated Test"
$string2 = $complicatedString2 -f $string1              # --> "This is a complicated Test too"

$string1 = $complicatedString1 -f "question"            # --> "This is a complicated question"
$string2 = $complicatedString2 -f $string1              # --> "This is a complicated question too"
```

You can also use the `Format` method of the string **object** itself if you like:

```
$string1 = [string]::Format($complicatedString1, "Test")
$string2 = [string]::Format($complicatedString2, $string1)
```

which will give you the exact same results

- [PowerShell -f operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html)
- [String.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Great answer which helped me to solve my problem satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to put you `complicatedString1` and `complicatedString2` in single quotes (otherwise they will be directly expanded), than you might use the `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString` method:

```
$complicatedString1 = 'This is a complicated $string1'
$complicatedString2 = '$complicatedString1 too'

$string1 = 'Test'

$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($complicatedString1)
This is a complicated Test
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($complicatedString2))
This is a complicated Test too

$string1 = "question"

$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($complicatedString1)
This is a complicated question
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($complicatedString2))
This is a complicated question too
```

*Note that you will need to use the `ExpandString` method twice on the `$complicatedString2` to get to the bottom of the `$string1` expansion.*

To get a better overview, you might consider to create a recursive function with a `-Depth` parameter:

```
Function Expand([String]$String, [Int]$Depth = 1) {
    $Expand = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($String)
    If ($Depth-- -ge 0) {Expand $Expand $Depth} Else {$Expand}
}

$string1 = 'Test'

Expand $complicatedString1
This is a complicated Test
Expand $complicatedString2 -Depth 2
This is a complicated Test too
```

Comment: Also a great answer with very useful information. The other answer was slightly more useful in my case though as it shows a way to have exact control over what to substitute.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it via a loop

```
do {
    $string1 = Read-Host "Please enter a word"
    $complicatedString1 = "This is a complicated $string1"; $complicatedString1
    $complicatedString2 = "$complicatedString1 too`n"; $complicatedString2
} while ($string1 -ne "exit program")
```

Output

```
Please enter a word: Test
This is a complicated Test
This is a complicated Test too

Please enter a word: Question
This is a complicated Question
This is a complicated Question too

Please enter a word: Exit Program
This is a complicated Exit Program
This is a complicated Exit Program too
#Program Exits#
```

Comment: Code only answers are not encouraged here, can you explain the context how this answer will help..