# What is an expandable string in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, grammar, string-interpolation

In PowerShell's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.1), I have come across the expression *expandable string*:

> Argument mode is designed for parsing arguments and parameters for commands in a shell environment. All input is treated as an *expandable string* unless it uses one of the following syntaxes:

Unfortunately, I am unable to find a definition for *expandable string* and my question is: what is an *expandable string* in PowerShell?

Comment: Do the answers to [How to expand variable in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915420/how-to-expand-variable-in-powershell) explain it for your purposes?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: yes, they answer my question.

Comment: You might also want to research the following Function: $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is definitely unfortunate that, as of this writing, the official help topic on PowerShell string literals, [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules) doesn't introduce the term *expandable string* [*update*: the online version now does; to also see the update locally, you may have to run [`Update-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/update-help)].

An ***expandable string*** is:

- A ***double*-quoted** string *literal* (`"..."`)

  - By contrast, a *single*-quoted string (`'...'`) is a *verbatim* (literal) string.
  - For an overview of all types of PowerShell string literals, which includes *here-string* variants (e.g., `@"<newline>...<newline>"@`), see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375).
- Double-quoted strings perform ***string interpolation* (expansion)**.

  - This allows you to embed simple variable references as-is (e.g, `"$var"`), and expressions and whole statements via `$()` (e.g., `"$($var.property)"`). Escape *verbatim* `$` (and `"`) chars. with `` ` ``. Enclose variable names in `{...}` for disambiguation (e.g. `"${var}"`).
  - For the complete rules, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375).