# How to make ($Line_1`n$Line_2) work in a CMD script?

Tags: powershell, cmd, escaping, special-characters

I use the following code in a CMD script file

```
PowerShell Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;^
$Line_1 = 'Hello!';^
$Line_2 = 'How are you?';^
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Line_1)
```

The above will show only **`($Line_1)`**
If **`` ($Line_1`n$Line_2) ``** is used, nothing will be shown.

How do I make it show both **`$Line_1`** and **`$Line_2`**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously `` $Line_1 + "`n" + $Line_2 `` and `` "$Line_1`n$Line_2" `` works normally. It's just tricky to send the command string to PowerShell from cmd with its legacy quirks because:

- In cmd `()` are special characters in various places denoting a block
- The token delimiter is not only `<space>` and `<tab>` but also [`;` `,` `=` `<0x0B>` `<0x0C>` and `<0xFF>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/995714). This changes tokenization behavior of cmd, but the command being called may reparse the command using its rules one more time

According to the documentation PowerShell <s>expects the command in a *single string* in the last parameter</s> (which isn't quite true since the document wasn't updated correctly), so you need to **quote the whole thing** or escape all the delimiters. The easiest solution is to use a single line and escape the quotes in `` "`n" `` like this

```
PowerShell "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; $Line_1 = 'Hello!'; $Line_2 = 'How are you?'; [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Line_1 + \"`n\" + $Line_2)"
```

If you want to put the commands in multiple lines then you can't quote the string. To put the whole thing as a single argument now you need to escape all the spaces (somehow you don't need to escape `;` in this case, possibly because after the command line is passed to PowerShell, it calls `GetCommandLineW` and parses again the whole thing itself)

```
PowerShell Add-Type^ -AssemblyName^ System.Windows.Forms;^
$Line_1^ =^ 'Hello!';^
$Line_2^ =^ 'How^ are^ you?';^
[Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Line_1^ +^ \"`n\"^ +^ $Line_2)"
```

Alternatively you can avoid that `` "`n" `` string by getting the new line directly with `[char]10`

```
PowerShell -Command Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;^
$Line_1 = 'Hello!';^
$Line_2 = 'How are you?';^
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Line_1 + [char]10 + $Line_2)
```

Finally a solution that works without any escaping which utilizes the `EncodedCommand` option of PowerShell which receives the base64 encoded string of a UTF-16 command string. You can get the encoded version by running this in PowerShell

```
$str = @'
>> Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;
>> $Line_1 = 'Hello!';
>> $Line_2 = 'How are you?';
>> [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Line_1 + "`n" + $Line_2)
>> '@
PS C:\Users> [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($str))
QQBkAGQALQBUAHkAcABlACAALQBBAHMAcwBlAG0AYgBsAHkATgBhAG0AZQAgAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAC4AVwBpAG4AZABvAHcAcwAuAEYAbwByAG0AcwA7AAoAIAA9ACAAJwBIAGUAbABsAG8AIQAnADsACgAgAD0AIAAnAEgAbwB3ACAAYQByAGUAIAB5AG8AdQA/ACcAOwAKAFsAUwB5AHMAdABlAG0ALgBXAGkAbgBkAG8AdwBzAC4ARgBvAHIAbQBzAC4ATQBlAHMAcwBhAGcAZQBCAG8AeABdADoAOgBTAGgAbwB3ACgAIAArACAAIgAKACIAIAArACAAKQA=
```

After having the encoded version you can call this from cmd

```
PowerShell -EncodedCommand QQBkAGQALQBUAHkAcABlACAALQBBAHMAcwBlAG0AYgBsAHkATgBhAG0AZQAgAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAC4AVwBpAG4AZABvAHcAcwAuAEYAbwByAG0AcwA7AAoAJABMAGkAbgBlAF8AMQAgAD0AIAAnAEgAZQBsAGwAbwAhACcAOwAKACQATABpAG4AZQBfADIAIAA9ACAAJwBIAG8AdwAgAGEAcgBlACAAeQBvAHUAPwAnADsACgBbAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAC4AVwBpAG4AZABvAHcAcwAuAEYAbwByAG0AcwAuAE0AZQBzAHMAYQBnAGUAQgBvAHgAXQA6ADoAUwBoAG8AdwAoACQATABpAG4AZQBfADEAIAArACAAIgBgAG4AIgAgACsAIAAkAEwAaQBuAGUAXwAyACkA
```

Comment: Nicely done; as for how PowerShell parses its command line with (implied) `-Command` / `-c` and _multiple_ arguments: it strips enclosing syntactic `"..."` quoting from each, if present, and concatenates them with a single space as a separator. The resulting string is then interpreted as a PowerShell command. You can see this in action with `powershell -nop -c "'["    "a"    "]'"`, which PowerShell ends up seeing and executing as `'[ a ]'`

Comment: @mklement0 that was also my thought but I couldn't confirm with `powershell -help`, unlike `cmd /?` where it clearly states that the outer quotes are usually stripped off

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the [PowerShell documentation of the `-Command` CLI parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh?view=powershell-7.2#-command---c) is lacking here. While it is generally improving, especially since [going open-source](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues), there are still cases where experimentation / reading the source code is needed.

Comment: P.S.:  `; , =` are only special (act as argument separators) when you call _batch files_, and, similarly, you're free to use `( )`  in arguments (even for batch files). I suggest correcting the claim that "PowerShell expects the command in a _single string_ in the last parameter", which isn't true (see my first comment).

Comment: It turns out that, even when calling something _other_ than a batch file, characters  `; , = ( )` can _situationally_ be special and then require `^`-escaping, namely if the call happens _inside a `for /f` statement_. Gotta love `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is (note the `` \"$Line_1`n$Line_2\" `` part):

```bash
PowerShell -c Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; ^
  $Line_1 = 'Hello!'; ^
  $Line_2 = 'How are you?'; ^
  [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(\"$Line_1`n$Line_2\")
```

<sup>Note that I've explicitly added the `-c` (`-Command`) parameter name to signal that a PowerShell command string is being passed. While that isn't necessary in *Windows PowerShell*, which defaults to `-Command`, it is in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, where `-File` is now the default - see the *CLI documentation* for [Windows PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) and [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh).</sup>

That is, you must **use `` $Line_1`n$Line_2 `` inside `"..."`, an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375)**, and you **must `\`-escape the `"` characters** so that PowerShell doesn't strip them as part of its command-line parsing (in the absence of *overall* double-quoting, `"""` works too).

---

**Unfortunately, the parsing rules *change* when [`for /f`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for) is used** in order to process PowerShell's output line by line and/or capture it in a variable:

<sup>Note: The following uses `[Console]::WriteLine()` so as to produce console output, just for the sake of using similar syntax to the `[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show()` method call while allowing something to be captured by `for /f`. In real life there is *no* good reason to call `[Console]::WriteLine()`.</sup>

```bash
for /f "delims=" %%l in ('

  PowerShell -c Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms^; ^
    $Line_1 ^= 'Hello!'^; ^
    $Line_2 ^= 'How are you?'^; ^
    [Console]::WriteLine^(\"$Line_1`n$Line_2\"^)

') do echo [%%l]
```

- `= , ; ( )` must *additionally* be escaped (outside what `cmd.exe` sees as a `"..."` string).
- If you additionally enclose a `\"...\"` string in `"..."` to prevent whitespace normalization (see next section) you must `^`-escape the enclosing (outer) `"`; e.g.,
  `^"\"Marley    &      Me\"^"`
- The line continuations (`^` at the end of command-interior lines) are actually *optional* inside `for /f`, but they were included for consistency.

---

**Summary of quoting and escaping requirements**:

- Your multi-line technique with line continuations (`^` at the end of lines) - which syntactically *cannot* use `"..."` quoting around the *entire* command, because `cmd.exe` doesn't support double-quoted multi-line *strings* - requires careful `^`-escaping of all `cmd.exe` metacharacters that should be passed through to *PowerShell*, notably `& | < > ^`, and, additionally, *if PowerShell is called from inside a `for /f` statement*, `, ; = ( )` - unless these characters happen to be part of a substring that `cmd.exe` sees as *double*-quoted; e.g.,  a `&` placed inside the `\"...\"` string - e.g.  `` \"$Line_1`n & $Line_2\" `` - must *not* be `^`-escaped (but see below re whitespace normalization).

  - As an exception, metacharacter `%` must always be escaped as `%%` (which only works in *batch files*, not at the command prompt - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420292/45375)).
  - Additionally, if `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is in effect (or `cmd.exe` was started with `/V:ON`), `!` must be escaped too, but inexplicably as follows:

    - As `^^!` (sic) *outside* of what `cmd.exe` sees as a `"..."` string (where the other metacharacter require just *one* `^`)
    - As `^!` *inside* such a string (where the other metacharacters require *no* escaping).
  - When calling via `for /f`, line continuations are *optional* - that is, you may omit the `^` at the end of the command-interior lines.
- Each statement must be `;`-terminated (as you have done), because the line-continuation (`^`) results in *no* newline between the input lines, so PowerShell sees them as a single line on which multiple statements must be `;`-separated.
- Because neither `cmd.exe` nor PowerShell's *initial* command-line parsing knows about single-quoted strings (`'...'`) and because the *escaped* `"` characters in `\"...\"` strings have no *syntactic* function during command-line parsing, such strings are broken into *multiple* arguments if they contain whitespace:

  - In effect, runs of *multiple* adjacent spaces inside such strings are normalized to a *single* space each. E.g., `'How   are      you?'` and `\"How   are      you?\"` are ultimately seen as `'How are you?'`and `"How are you?"` by PowerShell.
  - To avoid that, *additionally* enclose such strings in `"..."` :

    - *Single*-quoted PowerShell strings: `"'How   are      you?'"`

      - Note: This is *not* necessary if the *entire command* is enclosed in `"..."`
    - *Double*-quoted PowerShell strings: `^"\"How   are      you?\"^"`.

      - The `^`-escaped enclosing `"` chars. ensure that `cmd.exe` still sees what is between the inner `\"...\"` as double-quoted (because it doesn't recognize `\` as an escape char.), obviating the need to `^`-escape `cmd.exe` metacharacters there.
      - Note: If the *entire command* is enclosed in `"..."`, a different approach is required: use `"... "^""How   are      you?"^""  ..."` with `powershell.exe` (Windows PowerShell), and `"... ""How   are      you?"" ..."` with `pwsh.exe` (PowerShell (Core) 7+).
- In case you want to include *comments* in the PowerShell code, you must use the form
  `^<# ... #^>` - i.e. (escaped) *inline* comments - normal single-line comments (`# ....`) are *not* supported (because it would require a *newline* to terminate them, but there are no newlines between statements in the invocation method at hand).

---

**How PowerShell parses the arguments passed to its CLI's `-Command` / `-c` parameter:**

PowerShell gives you the choice between passing the command string

- either: as a *single* argument, enclosed in overall `"..."`; e.g.:

  - `powershell -c "Get-Date -Format 'yyyy MMM'"`
- or: *multiple* arguments - possibly individually `"..."`-quoted - which PowerShell then joins to form a single string; e.g.:

  - `powershell -c Get-Date -Format "'yyyy MMM'"`

In both cases, *unescaped* `"` characters are *stripped* from the argument(s), as they are assumed to have merely syntactic function for the sake of the *command line* rather than the resulting PowerShell command.

After stripping syntactic `"` characters and joining the resulting arguments with spaces, if applicable, Powershell interprets the resulting string *as PowerShell code*.

Note: This differs fundamentally from how arguments are parsed when you use the `-File` CLI parameter to invoke a *script file* and pass arguments to it - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375) for more.

Comment: You are right. Escaping characters is the simplest solution. Slash marks escaped me. I usually use single quotation marks.

Comment: @MatthewWai, with _single_-quoted strings (`'...'`) you won't get string interpolation, which is what is needed here. Note that `"""` instead of `\"` would have worked in this case too.

Comment: If multiple adjacent spaces are needed, I will use **`$Line_2 = '"Why     so?"';^`**

Comment: @MatthewWai, I would reverse the quotes, for conceptual clarity: `$Line_2 = "'Why     so?'"` - that way, with `"` quotes getting stripped, it is more obvious that PowerShell will see a `'...'` (verbatim) string rather than a `"..."` (interpolating) string.

Comment: @MatthewWai, I've updated the answer to generalize the information about passing strings with protection against whitespace normalization, and in doing so I've stumbled on the fact that - unfortunately - different parsing rules apply when PowerShell is called via `for /f` - please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to concatenate strings which you can look up, but probably the easiest way is to use the + symbol.  `n is a newline character which will place Line 2 below line 1.  Note that ` is a backtick symbol (usually on same key as the tilde ~)

```
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Line_1 + "`n" + $Line_2)
```

After looking again at your post I noticed you were close with ($Line_1`n$Line_2).  You're only missing some double-quotes

```
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$Line_1`n$Line_2")
```

Powershell is happy to replace variables with their values when placed inside double-quotes.  You can read more about expandable strings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65253528/what-is-an-expandable-string-in-powershell) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: **```($Line_1 + "`n" + $Line_2)```** does not work. Nothing is shown.

Comment: **```("$Line_1`n$Line_2")```** does not work either. Nothing is shown.

Comment: At the end of each line I just noticed you have ^ characters.  Those should not be there.  Also, ending each statement with a semi-colon is optional if you are adding a line break.  Also, remove powershell from the first line.

Comment: @Daniel the OP is calling powershell from cmd so `^` must be used to escape new lines

Comment: Ah, did not realize that.  Thank you @phuclv.  I don't usually see powershell script being run directly from cmd prompt.  That explains somethings about the code :)

Comment: The problem is that **`n** does not work in a CMD script. The backtick could be the culprit.

Comment: Double-quotes also do not work.  Cannot figure out how to send a newline character.  I can at least concat 2 strings `POWERSHELL 'this' + ' and that'` but stuck on what to do for newline.

Comment: All joke aside, are we just doing this for fun or is there a real need to be sending powershell code directly from cmd prompt.  Could you instead maybe write real powershell code inside a ps1 file and call the script file from cmd instead?

Comment: I often use PowerShell codes in a CMD script, but I am stuck in the said problem. I want to combine CMD and PowerShell into a single script.

Comment: @MatthewWai the backtick has nothing to do with this because it's just a normal character to cmd. Only `()` and `;` are special in this case. Anyway if you often use PowerShell it's better to just use PowerShell entirely to avoid all the legacy things of cmd