# Powershell: se variable in command

Tags: python, powershell

I'm facing a basic and stupid problem on Windows PowerShell. I'm almost sure it has already been answered somewhere but I can't find something working for me.

I simply would like to use a variable inside a command in PowerShell:

```
$VENV_DIR='C:\venv\'
python -m venv $VENV_DIR
$VENV_DIR\Scripts\python.exe --version
```

I expect to see `Python 3.10.8` as result.

But I have this error:

```
 PS C:\> $VENV_DIR\Scripts\python.exe --version
At line:1 char:10
+ $VENV_DIR\Scripts\python.exe --version
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '\Scripts\python.exe' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErr
   orRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

I tried a lot of different combinations, but none of them work

```
  97 $VENV_DIR\Scripts\python.exe --version
  98 `$VENV_DIR\Scripts\python.exe --version
  99 $VENV_DIR\\Scripts\python.exe --version
 100 $VENV_DIR\Scripts\python.exe --version
 101 "$VENV_DIR"\Scripts\python.exe --version
 102 "$VENV_DIR\Scripts\python.exe" --version
 103 "$VENV_DIR\Scripts\python.exe --version"
 104 ("$VENV_DIR\Scripts\python.exe --version")
 105 $("$VENV_DIR\Scripts\python.exe --version")
 106 -$("$VENV_DIR\Scripts\python.exe --version")
 107 -$("$VENV_DIR")\Scripts\python.exe --version
 108 -$($VENV_DIR)\Scripts\python.exe --version
 109 $VENV_DIR\Scripts\python.exe --version
 110 (echo $VENV_DIR)\Scripts\python.exe --version
 111 echo $VENV_DIR\Scripts\python.exe --version
 112 $(echo $VENV_DIR)\Scripts\python.exe --version
 113 -$(echo $VENV_DIR)\Scripts\python.exe --version
 114 -$("echo $VENV_DIR")\Scripts\python.exe --version
 115 echo $VENV_DIR\Scripts\python.exe --version
```

Could you please help? Thanks

Comment: 1) you forgot a `'` at the end, 2) aren't strings in Powershell supposed to be double-quoted anyway? This might just be a Powershell syntax error.

Comment: Oops sorry, For 1) it's only a copy-paste mistake. I've updated the config.

Comment: @shadowtalker strings in powershell can be `'single quoted'` or `"double quoted"`. Only cmd doesn't allow single quotes

Comment: @shadowtalker both single-quoted and double-quoted strings are valid, with different semantics. The difference is that `$` variables get expanded in a double-quoted string and not in a single-quoted string.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not really answering my question :(  See the tests I did. I tried with `"` and `$`

Comment: Is it the doubling of the backslash? `$VENV_DIR\Scripts` evaluates to `C:\venv\\Scripts` not `C:\venv\Scripts`

Comment: @slothrop It was a good idea but still the error :/

Comment: Sorry :( How about `& "$VENV_DIR\Scripts\python.exe --version"` ?

Comment: Still not working. I also tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915420/how-to-expand-variable-in-powershell without success

Comment: :( Third time lucky? `& "$VENV_DIR\Scripts\python.exe" --version`

Comment: Ok, this time it's better. At least powershell translates the variable. But still not working because of: ` The term 'C:\venv\Scripts\python.exe' is
not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program.`

Comment: Does that file exist in that directory?

Comment: Wouldn't you rather expect python to exist at `$VENV_DIR\bin\python.exe`?
`

Comment: Without the variable it works: ``` C:\> C:\venv\Scripts\python.exe --version
Python 3.10.8```

Comment: OK, sorry, I can't reproduce this and I'm stuck - the command with `&` and a variable works fine on my setup (admittedly not with identical directory names to yours)

Comment: Finally solved. The problem came from the way I declared the variable: `$VENV_DIR='C:\venv'`  --> `$VENV_DIR="C:\venv"` (double quote)

Comment: Interesting, for me it works with either single or double quotes - weird! But great you could get it fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting an ampersand before the python command?